# When using Emacs do you rebind caps-lock to CTRL?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-layout, remap

This question is, as indicated, for those who use Emacs.

When you do, do you rebind the caps-lock key to CTRL, or do you use the "normal" ctrl key?

I've recently learned some Emacs commands and was using the Visual Studio 2008 emacs commands for a while, and of course I used a caps-rebind tool, but I'm curious how many other people do.

On a side note, the emacs bindings for VS are severely incomplete :(

Comment: Kind of a closed question, are there any other answers than, "yes" "no" and perhaps "sometimes"?

Comment: I wonder how hard it would be to make a hardware interface - just something to plug your keyboard into - that captures any caps-lock stroke and remaps to control.

Comment: yes. caps lock to ctrl is awesome. and has saved my hands many cramps. i do it at the system level so it works for everything, opening a new tab in my browser (caps + T)... yay!

Comment: Wow... I've had my caps key rebound for a while but I'm so used to pushing the "other" control that I completely forgot that one exists. Also, ctrl + backspace when typing in a "normal" window! I have been enlightened...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no use for Caps Lock under any circumstances, whether I'm using Emacs or any other program.  In the rare case that I need to type several capital letters at once, I can easily hold down Shift with my left pinkie and type almost as fast as normal with my remaining fingers.  If I ever needed to produce a large amount of all-caps text using Emacs, I'd just type it all in lower case, select it, and upcase it all at once with <kbd>C-x C-u</kbd>, aka [upcase-region](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Case-Changes.html).

So yes, I do make Caps Lock an additional Control key.  I don't just swap them, I eliminate Caps Lock entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an emacs user, but I use Unix heavily with programs such as screen (and, *cough*, vim) which use control a lot, and I bind my caps lock to control.  Caps lock is a useless key that should have never made the typewriter->computer transition.

Comment: I think a lot of vim users rebind caps lock to escape! It doesn't need control a whole lot like emacs does.

Comment: @Jefromi: I hit `^V` and `^W` all day long in vim...

Comment: Sure, there are a few things, but emacs needs meta or control for basically everything, yeah? While Vim tends to need a lot of mode toggling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I do remap CAPSLOCK to control.

Comment: can you do that in a Mac? Sorry, I am a newbie and I read elsewhere you can't do that in a Mac unless you do that for the whole computer (which I don't want to do). I don't even know whether you use a mac (and I would guess not - you use linux?) but decided to try anyway....

Answer (score 1):

I kept one of my old Sun keyboards with control where God intended it until it would not work with the new UltraSparcs.  Ever since I have always remapped them, even if it did result in some odd blinking light behavior on some machines.

Comment: +1 for the "God intended" - if He had meant for us to use caps that frequently, uppercase would be the default and we'd use shift to lower-case things! (Also I wonder if ALL CAPS would be as prevalent on the intartubes if the caps-lock was where it belongs...)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely yes, and I'm really happy with it. Caps Lock is simply unuseful and irritating, switching it to a Ctrl will:

- Save you from awkward positions
- Save you from accidentally activating Caps Lock

Answer (score 0):

I also have useless MSWindows on my keyboard, so now I have three Ctrl keys on the left-hand side: Caps Lock, Ctrl, and LWin.

RWin generates "menu", which runs execute-extended-command (just like M-x). I'd never even tried pressing it until last week, so I don't know how long that's been the case for, but I'm trying to get accustomed to it.

I'm also trying to get used to using the right-hand Ctrl key when the keys to be modified are on the left side of the keyboard, and not in immediate range of (one of) the left Ctrl keys.

Answer (score 0):

I do, both on windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

A show of hands?  I have been using Emacs on and off over the past 5 years or more.  Never bothered about the caps lock key.  I do not bind it to control key.  C-x C-u did the work every time.  I can't recall any instance of having hit the caps lock when i was reaching out to 'a' or tab or 'shift'.

My be it it time for me to change the key binding.  I get pain in the hands while typing.  I'm going to try and see if having caps lock as control helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using 'alt' as 'ctrl' and 'win' as 'alt' is better than the well known 'capslock' method.

Google 'lisp keyboard' you'll get a better idea what I'm suggesting and why Emacs has so many 'ctrl' combinations in the first place -- at the time it's invented the keyboard layouts doesn't look like what it is today.

After failed multiple times trying to use 'capslock' as 'ctrl', now I love the 'alt' way.

Comment: Ahh... yeah, the caps-lock where it belongs - underneath the shift key on a nice tiny key - just like my typewriter.